# If I use AJAX to run an external .PHP file, does it have access to my .PHP includes?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm sure this is a quickie. I have a PHP application I'm working on, and I'm designing the form validation/processing; the file will be called via AJAX.

My question is: when I call the form validation .PHP file via AJAX, will it have access to my previously declared .PHP includes?

For example, if I have a `class User` already included on the page calling the AJAX file, will I be able to call `new User` or `User::authenticate` inside my form validation .PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: the php file you call should have all the necessary files in order to run. just like you would call it if you were opening the page on the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each invocation of php stands alone. It has no knowledge of what ran before it.

And it makes no difference that it's ajax. ajax calls are identical to simply browsing to the page regularly. It's just another way to display it in the browser, not another way to run php.

Answer (score 0):

if you include it in your validation .PHP file yes, otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

AJAX won't have any access to your PHP, it will merely have access to the output of your PHP. On the other hand, your PHP script will definitely have access on the included files.

You will be able to call `new User`, and then `User::authenticate`, but not only the last one alone.